# Converting raw file content from Flask file upload into dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am trying to upload a `csv` file to my flask server. What I want to do is to read its content into a `dataframe` without saving it on the file system. For now I'm using the `file.read()` method to get the contents of the file, but I'm at loss when it comes to converting these content into a pandas `dataframe`. Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files.get('uploaded_file')
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

    file_content = file.read()
    # want to convert these file content into a pandas dataframe
```

I am able to load it as a dataframe when saving to the disk, but I want to parse the content without saving the uploaded file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv()` can take any file-like object (with a `read()` method) as input, so just use it: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    df = pandas.read_csv(request.files.get('uploaded_file'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just a quick question, will it work for files with extensions `xls` or `xlsx` as well or just `csv`?

Comment: `pandas.read_csv()` is made for CSV input. If you want to read other formats, you need to use the other available methods such as `pandas.read_excel()` (which also accepts an opened file as input). You will have to detect the input type, for example by using the uploaded filename extension, or adding a post parameter whose value depends on the file format.